# Check user input value in function in R

Tags: r

I am having problem with function in R. I would like to write a function named myfunc for example like this:

```
myfunc<-function(X,a=100,b=10){}
```

With X is a matrix `mxn`, and a,b are the numbers such that `a<=m`, and `b<=n`

I would like to put the condition in my function that if the user don't input anything, a and b will be assigned to 100 and 10 automatically.

Otherwise, check and make sure to ask the user re-inputs a and b repeatedly until they satisfy `a<=m` and `b<=n`.

Could you guys please help me with this? I am learning about function in R. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add how user make unputs?

Comment: you need to provide more information about the user inputs and the expected outputs. What do you mean by "until they satisfy the condition above"? What condition?

Comment: Sorry, the condition I mentioned are a<=m and b<=n. I mean that if I input a>m or b>n, it will ask me to re-input the value a and b again. Is it possible to do this in function in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would throw an error:

```
myfunc<-function(X, a = 100, b = 10){
  if (a > nrow(X)) stop("a can't be greater than number of matrix rows")
  if (b > ncol(X)) stop("b can't be greater than number of matrix columns")
  return("Success!")
}
```

Your idea of asking for re-input is not good practice.

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you for the answer. I would like to ask that after throw an error, are there any way that the function ask to re-input the values?

Comment: It is possible, but not something you should do. Let the function exit with an error and let the user call the function again with correct input.

Comment: Oh right I got it now. I thought that my function should also check the input. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If for examlple you use http://www.r-bloggers.com/user-input-using-tcltk/ for user unputs

You can write something like

```
h=0
while(h==0){
  d1=unlist(varEntryDialog(vars= c('a','b'), labels=c('a:','b:'), fun= c(as.numeric,as.numeric )))
  if(!is.na(d1[[1]])&!is.na(d1[[2]])){
    if(is.numeric(d1[[1]])&d1[[1]]<=m&is.numeric(d1[[2]])&&d1[[2]]<=n) {
      h=1} else { 
        tkmessageBox(title = "Error",message = "bad a and b", icon = "error", type = "ok")}
  }else{
    tkmessageBox(title = "Error",message = "need a and b", icon = "error", type = "ok")}
}
rm(h)
```

But realy you need to more explanation to question.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to attempt to capture all of the errors and return them in a single error message.

```
myfunc <- function(X, a=100, b=10){
  require(ArgumentCheck)
  Check <- newArgCheck()
  if (a > nrow(X))
    addError("a can't be greater than number of matrix rows",
             Check)
  if (b > ncol(X))
    addError("b can't be greater than number of matrix columns",
             Check)
  finishArgCheck(Check)

 return("Success!")
}

myfunc(mtcars, a = 100, b = 30)

Error: 
myfunc(mtcars, a = 100, b = 30)
1: a can't be greater than number of matrix rows
2: b can't be greater than number of matrix columns
```